# Postman setNextRequest and workflow conditional workflow

Tags: rest, postman-testcase

I am trying to create a conditional workflow using setNextRequest. This workflow should do subsequent API call only when statuscode of current call is 201

My test looks something like this

```
var returnData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["status code"] = (responseCode.code === 201);
if (responseCode.code == 201) {
    postman.setNextRequest('ConfigurationModel-Module');
}
```

But even when my API response is 409 subsequent API call are triggered in postman runner

Comment: What i'm seeing is bit strange . the first request goes in , fails(gives 409) the test but triggers the next request. Basically if (responseCode.code == 201) does not get evaluated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing you can add an else statement

```
else
 postman.setNextRequest(null);
```